# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'readline'

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to make a hangman game in python but i get the attribute error in my title. this is my code

[image]

I have no idea what might be causing this attribute error in my code. I think it might have something to do with my code not having the correct naming or it might be how i defined in-File

```
import random
import string


WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"


def load_words(inFile=0):
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    :param inFile:
    """
    
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    open('words.txt', 'r')

    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    words = line.split()
    print("  ", len(words), "words loaded.")
    return words
```

Error:

```
File "C:)Users\ ManyDog\ PycharmProjects\ hangman\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    wordlist = load_words ()
File "C:)Users\ ManyDog\PycharmProjects\hangman\main.py", line 27, in Load_words
    line = inFile. readline ()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: Apparently you passed this function an integer instead of a file object. (Maybe you did something like `from os import *`, shadowing the built-in `open` with `os.open`. This is one of the reasons `import *` is a bad idea.)

Comment: Could you please post all the code relevant to the question

Comment: @KirillMcQuillin import random
import string


WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"


def load_words(inFile=0):
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    :param inFile:
    """
    
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    open('words.txt', 'r')

    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    words = line.split()
    print("  ", len(words), "words loaded.")
    return words

Comment: @ManyDog Please edit your question to include this code. I cannot read the code in a comment.

Comment: And include the error message as text in a code block.

Comment: Looking at the call signature `inFile=0`, you seem to expect infile to be an integer but then use it as a file object. It would be useful to have the code that calls this function.

Comment: @ManyDog you expect `inFile` to be a file, because that is how you use it in the function, but you default it to an int, so you get yelled at by Python. Why do you default `inFile` to 0?

Comment: @tdelaney which function should i call back for inFile specifically?

Comment: Something calls `load_words`. If that bit of code used an open file object, the code would work. Without seeing the calling code, its a guess what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You default `inFile` to an `int` but then try to use it as a file object. Internal to the function, you open a file but since you don't use its returned file object, it is immediately closed.

Instead, read the opened file. In this example, I've used your hard coded file name as a default for the function.

```
def load_words(inFile="words.txt"):
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    :param inFile:
    """
    
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    with open(inFile) as fileObj:
        # line: string
        line = fileObj.readline()
    words = line.split()
    print("  ", len(words), "words loaded.")
    return words
```